# update, instead of replace, list used for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**How it is**

I have an array of objects called `vm.queued_messages` (`vm` is set to `this` in my controller), and `vm.queued_messages` is used in `ng-repeat` to display a list of `div`'s.

When I make an API call which changes the underlying model in the database, I have the API call return a fresh list of queued messages, and in my controller I set the variable `vm.queued_messages` to that new value, that fresh list of queued messages.

```
vm.queued_messages = data; // data is the full list of new message objects
```

**The problem**

This "full replacement" of `vm.queued_messages` worked exactly as I wanted, at first. But what I didn't think about was the fact that even objects in that list which had no changes to any properties were leaving and new objects were taking their place. This made no different to the display because the new objects had identical keys and values, they were technically different objects, and thus the `div`'s were secretly leaving and entering every time. THIS MEANS THERE ARE MANY UNWANTED `.ng-enter`'s AND `.ng-leave`'s OCCURRING, which came to my attention when I tried to apply an animation to these `div`'s when they entered or left. I would expect a single `div` to do the `.ng-leave` animation on some click, but suddenly a bunch of them did!

**My solution attempt**

I made a function `softRefreshObjectList` which updates the keys and values (as well as any entirely new objects, or now absent objects) of an existing list to match those of a new list, WITHOUT REPLACING THE OBJECTS, AS TO MAINTAIN THEIR IDENTITY. I matched objects between the new list and old list by their `_id` field.

```
softRefreshObjectList: function(oldObjs, newObjs) {
    var resultingObjList = [];
    var oldObjsIdMap = {};
    _.each(oldObjs, function(obj) {
        oldObjsIdMap[obj._id] = obj;
    });
    _.each(newObjs, function(newObj) {
        var correspondingOldObj = oldObjsIdMap[newObj._id];
        if (correspondingOldObj) {
            // clear out the old obj and put in the keys/values from the new obj
            for (var key in correspondingOldObj) delete correspondingOldObj[key];
            for (var key in newObj) correspondingOldObj[key] = newObj[key];
            resultingObjList.push(correspondingOldObj);
        } else {
            resultingObjList.push(newObj);
        };
    });
    return resultingObjList;
}
```

which works for certain things, but with other `ng-repeat` lists I get odd behavior, I believe because of the `delete`'s and values of the objects being references to other controller variables. Before continuing down this rabbit hole, I want to make this post in case I'm thinking about this wrong, or there's something I'm missing.

**My question**

Is there a more appropriate way to handle this case, which would either make it easier to handle, or bypass my issue altogether?

- Perhaps a way to signal to Angular that these objects are identified by their `_id` instead of their reference, so that it doesn't make them leave and enter as long as the `_id` doesn't change.
- Or perhaps a better `softRefreshObjectList` function which iterates through the objects differently, if there's something fishy about how I'm doing it.

Comment: if you have trouble with ng-enter ng-leave, remove ngAnimate or limit animations to a certain class name with something like $animateProvider.classNameFilter(/\banimated\b/);

Comment: can you put together a plunker or jsfiddle which shows your problem?

Comment: Have you tried 'track by'?

Comment: 'track by' looks perfect! from the [docs for ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) "If you are working with objects that have an identifier property, you should track by the identifier instead of the whole object. Should you reload your data later, ngRepeat will not have to rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones."

Comment: @PetrAveryanov you should put your comment into the answer... You deserve the rep..

Comment: @TirthrajBarot I agree, and don't mean to swipe it by making my own answer (and I did say that I got it from his comment). I just wanted the answer to be more visible in case someone else came by this question, cuz it's exactly what I needed. According to [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269913/comment-poaching), I did ok, but I apologize if it seems like I poached unfairly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Petr's comment, I now know about `track by` for `ng-repeat`. It's where you can specify a field in your elements that "identifies" that element, so that angular can know when that element really is leaving or entering. In my case, that field was _id, and adding `track by message._id` to my `ng-repeat` (`ng-repeat="message in ctrl.queued_messages track by message._id"`) solved my issue perfectly.

Docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). Search for `track by`.

Comment: Not at all tscizzle, You did the correct thing by mentioning his name here... But this is not enough to make it more visible... I am voting it up, even you should vote it up and mark it correct... That will help all thoise who face a similar problem... It would be unfair only if he would have put it in answer and still you add another answer and mark yourself correct.. But you really behaved ethical... Good job man..!